# Which one of these sites to start learning python? (complete beginner)

Tags: python

Sorry if this question isn't allowed, but of these 3 which one do you recommend for a complete beginner? (I have absolutely NO programming knowledge, this is my first ever language)

- [greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html)
- [thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=36](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=36)
- [net.tutsplus.com/sessions/python-from-scratch/](http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/python-from-scratch/)

Comment: I would recommend Udacity's "Building a Search Engine" class, aimed to total beginners. You are still on time (only a couple of weeks late) to catch up with this instance. http://udacity.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advice you to read all 3 link. You wont understand much if follow only one tutorial. Google python tutorial and you will get a lot link. Check which one suit for you. :)